# Google "Large" AdSense Number Limit (with AdSense Responsive Unit)

Tags: adsense

Reading Google's Policy, it clearly [states](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_the_same_page_or_site_as_another_publisher) that no more than **three ads** should be per page. It also states that out of those three ads you can only have **one "large" one**.

> Publishers may not place more than one "large" ad unit per page. We define a "large" ad unit as any unit similar in size to our 300x600 format. For example, this would include our 300x1050 and 970x250 formats, our 750x200 and 580x400 regional formats, and any other custom sized ad with comparable dimensions.

**QUESTION**

I am currently using **three responsive ad units** in a single page. Depending on the screen size, two of them have enough space to output a 970 px ad. Is that considered as breaking the policy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, two 970x90 ads on the same page are not a violation.

970x90 is "big" - it is 87.300 pixels total (`970 x 90 = 87.300`), but not bigger than 160x600 (which is `96.000`) and 336x280 (which is `94.080`).

That is why I believe it is not being considered as "large", and these are my calculations I'm basing my opinion on:

GPF: "One month, 1000 pages views (4000 by google analytics), 25 clicks = 0.50€"
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/EWCYW25ISpg/g0uu8bKAc4cJ

This is actually just my comment, but I'm writing it as answer because (I need more space, and because) I don't think you can get the definite answer to your question: "*I am currently using **three responsive ad units** in a single page. [...] Is that considered...*":

- If you **are not** using `data-ad-format` and you **are**
  using `@media` queries to control the height, then you need to make
  sure your ads won't be something `close|similar|not-even-comparable` to 970x250. (That is fairly
  easy, but not what you are asking about.)
- If you are using
  `data-ad-format`, then `adsbygoogle.js` is taking care about the
  size, but - you'll want to test your placements, and **if** you see more than one "large", then you'll probably want to
  [**convert your ad code**](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893#adv) (from "smart sizing" with
  `data-ad-format`, to "exact size per screen width") and to control the
  height with `@media` queries.

So I'm afraid *you* need to make sure all *your* placements (smart-sized, exact-size, fixed size, etc.) are in compliance: having two "large" ad units on the same page is a violation of AdSense policies.